# Dowloading and saving PDFs from a partial href?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to download and save all the files from: https://www.bankia.es/es/pymes-y-autonomos/buscador-documentacion-precontractual

There are more than 1200 files available so I was thinking about using some kind of loop. I realized that all of them contains the same partial href: href="/estaticos/documentosPRIIPS/xxxx.PDF"

Here it is what I tried:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
savepath = 'my_path' # set the desired path here for the files


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_experimental_option('prefs',  {
    "download.default_directory": "my_path",
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True
    }
)
url_bankia= "https://www.bankia.es/es/pymes-y-autonomos/buscador-documentacion-precontractual"
bankia_request = requests.get(url_bankia)
bankia_web = BeautifulSoup(bankia_request.text, "html.parser")
bankia_web.find_all("a", href=re.compile(r"^/estaticos/documentosPRIIPS/"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you wanna use selenium when you can achieve the same using requests module? Turn out that this very [URL](https://www.bankia.es/estaticos/documentosPRIIPS/json/jsonSimple.txt) contains json response from which you can extract the value of `nombre_de_fichero` and then add to the last part of this `https://www.bankia.es/estaticos/documentosPRIIPS/` to make a full-fledged link to the pdf files. One such link should look like `https://www.bankia.es/estaticos/documentosPRIIPS/AC-AM-AP-EX-12M-EUR-CAD-20190508.PDF`.

The following script will create a folder in your desktop location named `PdfFolder` in which the files are supposed to be downloaded.

```
import os
import requests

link = 'https://www.bankia.es/estaticos/documentosPRIIPS/json/jsonSimple.txt'
base = 'https://www.bankia.es/estaticos/documentosPRIIPS/{}'

dirf = os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + "\Desktop\PdfFolder"
if not os.path.exists(dirf):os.makedirs(dirf)
os.chdir(dirf)

res = requests.get(link,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
for item in res.json():
    if not 'nombre_de_fichero' in item: continue
    link = base.format(item['nombre_de_fichero'])
    filename = item['nombre_de_fichero'].split('.')[-2] + ".PDF"
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(requests.get(link).content)
```

Comment: Thank you vey much. It works perfectly. I am trying to reproduce similar code in this page [link](https://www.bankinter.com/banca/nav/documentos-datos-fundamentales) but it seems that it may have a different structure.

Comment: Try creating another post describing your current need and drop the link (your newly created post) here. I'll take a look. This time you need to send a post http requests to get the json response.

Comment: SIM, I have uploaded this new post, thanks for your help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56442694/how-to-download-and-save-all-pdf-from-a-dynamic-web