# How to download and save all PDF from a dynamic web?

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping, href

I am trying to download and save in a folder all the PDFs contained in some webs with dynamic elements i.e: https://www.bankinter.com/banca/nav/documentos-datos-fundamentales

Every PDF in this url have similar href. Here they are two of them:
"https://bancaonline.bankinter.com/publico/DocumentacionPrixGet?doc=workspace://SpacesStore/fb029023-dd29-47d5-8927-31021d834757;1.0&nameDoc=ISIN_ES0213679FW7_41-Bonos_EstructuradosGarantizad_19.16_es.pdf"

"https://bancaonline.bankinter.com/publico/DocumentacionPrixGet?doc=workspace://SpacesStore/852a7524-f21c-45e8-a8d9-1a75ce0f8286;1.1&nameDoc=20-Dep.Estruc.Cont.Financieros_18.1_es.pdf"

Here it is what I did for another web, this code is working as desired:

```
link = 'https://www.bankia.es/estaticos/documentosPRIIPS/json/jsonSimple.txt'
base = 'https://www.bankia.es/estaticos/documentosPRIIPS/{}'

dirf = os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + "\Documents\TFM\PdfFolder"
if not os.path.exists(dirf2):os.makedirs(dirf2)
os.chdir(dirf2)

res = requests.get(link,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
for item in res.json():
    if not 'nombre_de_fichero' in item: continue
    link = base.format(item['nombre_de_fichero'])
    filename_bankia = item['nombre_de_fichero'].split('.')[-2] + ".PDF"
    with open(filename_bankia, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(requests.get(link).content)
```

Comment: The webpage by default doesn't display any pdf files. You should describe in your post as to how they can be displayed in that webpage. Once they are in that page then we can help you download them.

Comment: I am trying to download every pdf shown when I select Categoría -> Renta Fija Privada and Familia -> Bonos Estructurados. I can not copy the url because it remains the same. It is like an internal searcher that does not modify the innitial url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make a post http requests with appropriate json parameter. Once you get the response, you have to parse two fields `objectId` and `nombreFichero` to use them to build right links to the pdf's. The following should work:

```
import os
import json
import requests

url = 'https://bancaonline.bankinter.com/publico/rs/documentacionPrix/list'
base = 'https://bancaonline.bankinter.com/publico/DocumentacionPrixGet?doc={}&nameDoc={}'
payload = {"cod_categoria": 2,"cod_familia": 3,"divisaDestino": None,"vencimiento": None,"edadActuarial": None}

dirf = os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + "\Desktop\PdfFolder"
if not os.path.exists(dirf):os.makedirs(dirf)
os.chdir(dirf)

r = requests.post(url,json=payload)
for item in r.json():
    objectId = item['objectId']
    nombreFichero = item['nombreFichero'].replace(" ","_")
    filename = nombreFichero.split('.')[-2] + ".PDF"
    link = base.format(objectId,nombreFichero)
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(requests.get(link).content)
```

After executing the above script, wait a little for it to work as the site is real slow.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this is working. How can I figure the payload for each selection? You have selected {"cod_categoria" : 2. "cod_familia: 3 ...} Is there a way to see the other possible selections? I really appreciate your help on this issue,

Comment: You can find everything by making use of chrome dev tools. when you open the dev tools, click on the network tab then xhr tab and then reload the page. once the page is reloaded, you can see different urls in it's left pane doing different activity. However, clicking either of the urls, you can see related information in it's right pane. You can search for google how chrome dev tools (network activity) work. If the above script works for you, care to accept it as a solution by ticking the grayed out checkmark next to my answer. Thanks.